# How to store jwt token so that redirecting to other subdomain doesn't require the credentials

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iphone, cookies, preact

How to store jwt token so that redirecting to other subdomains doesn't require the credentials. I am storing it in a cookie, but on iPhone, it is not working. It is asking for passwords when redirects to other subdomains.

```
function saveJWT(jwtKey, jwtValue) {
 let days;
 if(!days) {
  days = 365* 20;
 }
 const date = new Date();
 date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days* 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
 console.log(date)

 const expires = ';expires' + date.toUTCString();
 console.log(expires)
 const prodCookie = jwtKey+ "=" +jwtValue+ expires + 
 ";domain=.cerebry.co;path=/"
const devCookie = jwtKey+ "=" +jwtValue+ expires + "; path=/ "

if(location.hostname === "localhost"){
  document.cookie = devCookie;
}
else {
  document.cookie = prodCookie;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Cookie should work, make sure you set the right path and root domain when setting the cookie.
The 2 domains mydomain.com and subdomain.mydomain.com can only share cookies if the domain is explicitly named in the Set-Cookie header. Otherwise, the scope of the cookie is restricted to the request host.

if you use the following, it will be usable on both domains:
Set-Cookie: name=value; domain=mydomain.com

Since cookie can be stolen by XSS attack, make sure you prevent token sidetacking . Refer OWASP for securing your JWT auth mechanism
https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/JSON_Web_Token_for_Java_Cheat_Sheet.html

Comment: https://pastebin.com/BKi2qWDs
I am using this way to save, can you please what I am doing wrong here ?

Comment: i see the domain as .domain=.cerebry.co. remove the dot character at start.. For example if your domain is app.cerebry.co, then the domain should be set as ""cerebry.co". Also due to recent chrome changes with cookies make sure the cookies are set first, because it requires https domain if same-site attribute is not set

Comment: I changed to cerebry.co still it's not working for iPhone

Comment: what is the ios version of that iphone? did you try with an older iphone ?

Comment: try with a older ios version or try to debug through a mac, it should show some issue

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue saving a cookie in Iphone, so i used js-cookie Library which solved my problem
[JS COOKIE LINK](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie)

Comment: is it specific to that particular ios version or phone? because i heard safari had some issues with cookies in subdomain